# Ubuntu 18.04 crashed with a black screen using livepatch

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade, update-manager, syslog

For the second time in a week I found my Ubuntu 18.04 with a black screen in the morning. When I look in the syslog I see the PC crashed on 6:45 running livepatch. After get-updates the log shows only \00.

Mar 27 06:45:14 johan-NUC8i7BEH canonical-livepatch[1072]: Client.Check
Mar 27 06:45:14 johan-NUC8i7BEH canonical-livepatch[1072]: Checking with livepatch service.
Mar 27 06:45:14 johan-NUC8i7BEH canonical-livepatch[1072]: Updated last-check.
Mar 27 06:45:14 johan-NUC8i7BEH canonical-livepatch[1072]: No updates available at this time.
Mar 27 06:45:14 johan-NUC8i7BEH canonical-livepatch[1072]: No payload available.
Mar 27 06:46:42 johan-NUC8i7BEH PackageKit: get-updates transaction /1230_aaadbaee from uid 1000 finished with success after 435ms
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00